# ruby tdd best practice in dealing with obsolete tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm running through a very basic challenge at Code Wars. The challenge is to test-drive a method that returns the sum of an array of squares.

So far, my tests are:

```
describe "square method" do   
  it "should return the square of a number" do

    Test.assert_equals(squareSum(4), [16])

  end

  it "should return the square of multiple numbers" do 

    Test.assert_equals(squareSum(4, 2, 3), [16, 4, 9])

  end
end
```

and my code is:

```
def squareSum(*numbers)
  numbers.map { |num| num ** 2 }
end
```

Now I'm at the point where I need to change it so that it adds the sum. Which, in my mind, necessarily negates the two previous tests. As far as TDD best practices go, was I being ridiculous testing those first two scenarios, given that they aren't what I'm trying to get the method to do? How should I proceed with my next test?

Should I:

- delete the previous two tests, since they will fail once I change the method?
- find a way to make it so that the two previous tests don't fail even once I've changed it?

In approaching this problem, should I have not worried about the first two tests? I am having a fair amount of difficulty phrasing this question. Basically, what I know I want to end up with is:

```
describe "squareSum method" do 
  it "should return the sum of the squares of the numbers passed" do 

    Test.assert_equals(squareSum(1, 2, 2), 9)

  end
end
```

with the code to make it work. I'm just wondering what the best practices are in regards to test-driving this particular kind of problem, given that I wanted to test that I could return squares for multiple numbers before returning the sum. My "final" code will render the initial tests obsolete. This is a, "How much of my work should be present in the final solution?", picky and kind of anal-retentive question, I think. But I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tests are specifications for the software you intend to write, the question is why you wrote a specification for something you didn't want (since the task of the challenge was not write a function that squares its arguments)?

You should have written a specification for "a method that returns the sum of an array of squares" in the first place. This test starts out being red.

Then you may decide that you need a function that squares its arguments (or the elements of a given array) as an intermediate step. Write a test for this function. Make it green by implementing such a function.

Eventually put all the things together and make your initial test green (your main function could use the helper function and sum-up its return values).

No you can refactor. If during refactoring you decide that you no longer need the helper function: delete the function and delete its tests.

Also when your specifications are changing, you need to rewrite your tests, write new ones or even delete some of them.

But the general rule is: The tests are always a specification for the current state of your software. They should specify exactly what your software is intended to to. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Well, now I feel silly. :) Thank you. This clarified my puzzlement a great deal.